# Why we import import "core-js/stable" library?

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, create-react-app, polyfills, core-js

I'm in a process of optimising one react project. I can see "core-js/stable" is used. Is this package still required for latest browser ? since most browser support ES6 features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if it *may* not be currently required (there's no way to tell without looking at your code, and knowing precisely what versions of what browsers you want to support), what if a developer later uses a new feature in the app that needs to be polyfilled, even in modern browsers? To be on a safer side and automate the process, it's recommended to include `core-js/stable` before your entrypoint, declare the browsers you want to support in your project's `browserlist` (check out the [browserlist playground](https://browsersl.ist/)), and let `core-js/stable` only include the required polyfills in your bundle (according to the [caniuse](https://github.com/browserslist/caniuse-lite) database). Of course, remember that some polyfills may not be currently supported by `core-js/stable`, needing to be included separately.

An alternative approach may be to use [polyfill.io](https://polyfill.io/v3/url-builder), select `ES6` (and other polyfills you may need), generate your `URL` and include it at the top of your `head` tag. Compared to `core-js/stable`, the optimization advantage is that it includes a polyfill conditionally based on the user agent requesting the `URL`. It's a good advantage for very modern browsers, some of them may receive `0KB` of polyfills by `polyfill.io`. The disadvantage is that it doesn't work with `browserlist`, so it is more of your responsibility to know what polyfills your app needs, generate the correct [polyfill.io](https://polyfill.io/v3/url-builder) `URL`, and test your app on the oldest version you want to support for each browser.